# Source time is in ET and now it is running an hour ahead - Java

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm using the following code to convert the time to local time. It was running 'on time' but today it jumped ahead by an hour.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```

Using "ET" instead of "EST" doesn't work.

How can I correct the converted time?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting it to the "local time?" isn't that already done by default? If not, try: setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only show the code that creates the SimpleDateFormat, so apparently you are sure the problem is in there?

Debugging date/time/timezone/daylight savings related problems can be very difficult because it is very hard to 'see' the actual date; when you inspect it the Date's toString method will do some timezone conversion of it's own (based on current locale). So I find it most easy to convert all input to UTC and then print it out in UTC locale.

Anyway, you say 'ET' does not work? I have little experience with it, but if you look at the docs for [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) you should be able to come up with an algortithm o print out all timezones installed on your system. If EST differs from ET (does it?) then this will never work. You need to figure out the names Java has assigned to the ET timezone and use those to create the date formatter.

The trick is to parse the input (which is in locale X) using a date formatter for locale X and then use the Date (which is always in UTC, so timezone-neutral so to say) in your calculations. Then only go back to timezone X or Y for output by using a date format with the correct locale again.

Comment: I'm not using anything special for Day light savings time anywhere. ET returns the same output as GMT would. My source is in ET and I cannot change that on the server. EST displayed the proper output till today.

Comment: If your source is in ET and that is different from EST, then why would this ever work? Are you using the formatter to parse the source or to output it? If you are parsing with the wrong locale then problems are to be expected. Figure out how Java calls 'ET' and use that name. Or better yet, show us a full example that demonstrates the issue. Hardcode a source date if you need to. We are now talking in the abstract. Having an example will clear things up quickly.

Comment: I'm using the code to convert the ET time into the local time. ET - EST during winter (till yesterday) so it worked then. I still haven't found out how Java calls ET. That line of code is the all important line. Eg. If my source was in GMT and I replaced "EST" in there with "GMT", then it will work.. I only have to know how Java calls ET.

Comment: So, [loop over all Timezones and print out their names](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.nl/2010/08/get-all-timezones-available-in-timezone.html). It must have a name surely!  :)

Comment: Got the answer - 'America/New_York'! Why didn't they simply name it ET?

Comment: Probably it has multiple names. Anyway, glad you solved it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try using EDT.

I know that seems totally counter to what you are trying to do here, but you might have a double adjustment somewhere if it sees EST and tries to convert to EDT.

The fact that daylight savings just hit today really points to the TimeZone issue.

Comment: You are right, the daylight savings problem started today. Unfortunately, EDT doesn't help.